# Android emulator doesn't restore time when host computer wakes up from hibernate

Tags: android-emulator

Each time I wake up my host computer from hibernate, Visual Studio Emulator for Android keeps old time (the one from hibernating moment) - so I'm forced to re-run emulator to keep it actual. Any chances to workaround this?